# How do I code the Azure permissions to be Delegated in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a Powershell script to create an automated application in Azure and assign it certain permissions. When the application is completed, most permissions are set as 'Application' and I would like them to be set as 'Delegated'. See my photo below comparing the ideal application on the left versus the created application on the right. Does anyone know how to set these permissions as 'Delegated' in Powershell?

[image]

I'll include the code below that creates the permissions in Azure Powershell:

```
function Add-Permission {

    param(
        $App
    )

    $targetSpGraph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'"
    $appPermissionsRequired = @('User.Read.All','Group.Read.All','GroupMember.Read.All',`
    'GroupMember.ReadWrite.All','Directory.Read.All','AuditLog.Read.All')

    $RoleAssignmentsGraph = @()

    foreach ($AppPermission in $appPermissionsRequired) {
        $RoleAssignmentGraph = $targetSpGraph.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $AppPermission }
        $RoleAssignmentsGraph += $RoleAssignmentGraph
    }

    $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]'

    foreach ($RoleAssignmentGraph in $RoleAssignmentsGraph) {
        $resourceAccessGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess"
        $resourceAccessGraph.Id = $RoleAssignmentGraph.Id
        $resourceAccessGraph.Type = 'Role'
        $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph.Add($resourceAccessGraph)
    }

    $requiredResourceAccessGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAppId = $targetSpGraph.AppId
    $requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAccess = $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph

    $delPermissionGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182","Scope"
    $requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAccess += $delPermissionGraph

    $targetSpAzure = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Windows Azure Service Management API" }
    $delPermissionAzure = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033","Scope"

    $requiredResourceAccessAzure = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $requiredResourceAccessAzure.ResourceAppId = $targetSpAzure.AppId
    $requiredResourceAccessAzure.ResourceAccess = $delPermissionAzure

    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $App.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccessGraph, $requiredResourceAccessAzure

    Write-Output "Combined Permissions Added"

    return $App
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Delegated permissions are handled through *OAuth2PermissionGrant* objects instead of AppRoleAssignments.
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell.

I don't remember the exact parameters for the AzureAD module, but essentially you need to create an OAuth2PermissionGrant with:

- clientId: object ID of the service principal that will get the permission
- consentType: AllPrincipals (unless you want to grant this only with some users)
- principalId: null (or the objectId of a user)
- resourceId: object ID of the service principal that defines the permission (MS Graph in your case)
- scope: space-separated list of required permissions

You only need one of these per API that you want to call unless you want to grant the permission only for some users, in which case you need one per user as well.

Note that this is what grants the permissions to the application.
To keep it clean, I would usually recommend defining these permissions also on the *application* object in its required permissions.
This does not grant the permissions, though it allows an admin to click "Grant consent" and create all of the required AppRoleAssignments and OAuth2PermissionGrants through that.

You can check the application object contents here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0.

You would want to define the permissions under *requiredResourceAccess*.